# After upgrade to 20.04, no sound from Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

I am getting sound from other applications I've tried (Chromium, VLC, Videos), but nothing from Firefox.

Everything looks like it should be working. In sound settings, Firefox is turned up to 100% and when I play something, the output device even lights up like it thinks that sound is coming out, but it isn't.

Comment: In my case, Firefox sound was muted in the Volume Control Manager. I was complaining and suffering since weeks :(

Comment: I never did figure out the problem. IIRC, after a restart the problem went away and I haven't had it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install `pavucontrol`:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Select required sound device on the **Playback** tab if a few are installed:

[image]

Try different output channels on **Output Devices** tab if a few are available:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this is needed? Is it a bug in firefox?

Comment: @Étienne author says he had this behavior only in Firefox, so maybe the issue Firefox related. Also, if you install some aditional sound configuration tools and use them, it could cause sound disappearing issues after system restart

Comment: I had the same issue: sound working with google chrome but not with firefox. I'm just wondering whether this is something which should be reported to firefox bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome (Debian buster) I had the same problem on Youtube with Firefox only (system sound/Chrome and any other application was ok): I had to play a Youtube video, while playing the video I checked the Gnome sound system parameters and select "Applications" tab (you should see Firefox in the list), there the sound was only set to about 10%, I have no idea why...I suspect that this sound parameter has been changed by using VLC volume control...

Comment: OP says Firefox was turned up to 100%...

Comment: @Zanna is Firefox greyed out? It is nearly unperceptible. In my case it was. If it's your case, just click on it and it will reactivate.